# Flutter Web App: XMLHttpRequest error - responce headers _map<getObject>Unsupported operation :unknown library?

Tags: flutter, dart

Judging from many postings here a lot of people suffer from similar problems.

I have tried to understand the CORS protocol explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS and here
https://auth0.com/blog/cors-tutorial-a-guide-to-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

In my Flutter web App I make the following call:-

```
Future<http.Response> fetchWebData() async {
    return (http.get(Uri.parse('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/?email=a@b.com'))); 
}
```

The server is written is Java receives the following record:-

```
GET /?email=a@b.com HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozil
 la/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:58559
Referer: http://localhost:58559/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

From the inclusion of the "Origin" head I concluded this was a simple CORS request and replied with:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 23 May 2021 13:51:56 GMT
Server: MRS_Server
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 90
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"book": [{"id": "01","language": "Java","edition": "third","author": "Herbert Schildt"}]}
```

In an attempt to understand the problem I placed a breakpoint at

```
    unawaited(xhr.onError.first.then((_) {    <<<BREAKPOINT
      // Unfortunately, the underlying XMLHttpRequest API doesn't expose any
      // specific information about the error itself.
      completer.completeError(
          ClientException('XMLHttpRequest error.', request.url),
          StackTrace.current);
    }));
```

and looked at the request.headers._map which showed:-

```
<getObject>Unsupported operation :unknown library
```

Some references say the Content-type: should be "text/plain" whilst other show
I am hoping someone can explain what I doing wrong??
What is the unknown library??

Steve

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? I ran in the same issue today: Flutter 2.2.1 and HTTP Server in JAVA (default implementation).

Comment: I read the request header which stated that accepted response was for qzip encoded. <br>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2021 12:41:28 GMT
Server: MRS_Server
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Content-type: application/gzip
Content-Length: 90
Connection: Closed

{"book": [{"id": "01","language": "Java","edition": "third","author": "Herbert Schildt"}]}<br>I abbanded Web version as http:// not accepted by Chrome<br> Flutter client now hanging until timeout. Then gets data!

Answer (score 0):

My answer withdrawn I see there are other answers.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while was trying to make a GET / POST requests to a simple HTTP-Server based on Java.

After spending couple of days I figured out that the problem was really CORS-related and not Flutter relevant.

For me the solution was to include a header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *" on the server side:

```
httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

and this finally worked - now GET and POST requests are running fine.

One point to Flutter: imho the team could make this exception better documented.